# Python vs bash stderr stdout buffering

Tags: python, bash, buffer, stdout, stderr

How can I make my python script behave like bash with regards to stderr and stdout buffering?  Bash is buffering stderr and stdout so that printed messages appear in chronological order.  The example scripts below illustrate the behavior.  Tested with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04.

### cstderr.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "C out to stderr\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

### bash_stderr.sh

```
echo Before C cstderr
./cstderr.out
echo After C cstderr
```

### py_stderr.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
print("Before C cstderr")
subprocess.check_call("./cstderr.out")
print("After C cstderr")
```

### Bash behavior

```
$ ./bash_stderr.sh > outfile 2>&1
$ cat outfile
Before C cstderr
C out to stderr
After C cstderr
```

### Python behavior

```
$ ./py_stderr.py > outfile 2>&1
$ cat outfile 
C out to stderr
Before C cstderr
After C cstderr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash flushes stdout before any executing any external program. Python doesn't. To get the desired behavior, call `sys.stdout.flush()` immediately before the `subprocess.check_call()`.

Answer (score 2):

Look up the `-u` option in python's [miscellaneous options](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) section. It forces standard input, output and error to be unbuffered, so no flushing should be required.

For what it's worth, your program appears to work as expected without modification for both Python 2 and 3 on my Ubuntu 4.2.0-42-generic system, even without the `-u` option.